# How to Give Custom ItemStyle.xsl Path in CQWP of subsite?

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part, item-styles

I have CQWP that is in the SubSIte.I want to give it Custom ItemStyle.xsl path.I had done it by following Link.

```
<property name="ItemXslLink" type="string">/sites/test35/Style%20Library/XSL/WebPartItemStyle.xsl</property>
```

It works fine But when I edit WebPart it Shows the Error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog post covering this at http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/cqwp-and-xslt-part-1/. Essentially you will need to edit the web part in SharePoint Designer.  If you need to reuse it then you can export and import to the web part gallery and it can then be added to pages like any other web part.

Comment: But,I want to add Web Part programitically

Comment: Ah OK - then I am not the right person for advice - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ~siteCollection tokens for site collection or ~site token for a web:

```
<property name="ItemXslLink" type="string">~siteCollection/Style%20Library/XSL/WebPartItemStyle.xsl</property>
```

Comment: It works fine.But,when I edit the WebPart it throws the Error "Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object."

Comment: Have you looked at ULS log? `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS`

Comment: It says "Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object."

Comment: there is should be stack trace